# Devolver variable de jsp a otro jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hola buenas tengo un jsp con la siguiente funcion y me gustaría saber como poder llamarla en otro jsp...Gracias a todos!

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function getHeight(){
             var alto = document.getElementById('table').offsetHeight;
           return alto; 
       }
         
 
</script>
```

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: copiar el código tal cual o poner la función en un fichero js e importarlo en ambas páginas

Comment: El problema de si lo copio..es que me esta cogiendo la altura de una table de ese jsp @PabloLozano

Comment: Javascript se ejecuta en el lado del cliente, no puedes obtener el resultado de una operación en una página para usarlo en otra de la manera que planteas

Comment: Y como podría hacerlo , osea planteando de forma diferente??@PabloLozano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
       function getHeight(){
             var alto = document.getElementById('table').offsetHeight;
             document.getElementById('elemHeight').value = alto;
           return alto; 
       }                  
</script>
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="-1" id="elemHeight" name="elem">
```

JSP

Para recoger el dato en el JSP solo tienes que llamar a la funcion `getParameter()` con el nombre del elemento de tu formulario, `getParameter('elem')`

La mejor opción es guardar el valor en un input hidden y recuperarlo en el JSP cuando envíes el formulario. Para comprobar que el valor se pasa correctamente inicializas el "hidden" a -1 para comprobar en el jsp que el valor del input es distinto de -1. Si no tienes formulario puedes crearlo aunque solo sea para ese elemento.

Comment: Vale te refieres ha algo parecido a esto?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
       function getHeight(){
             var alto = document.getElementById('table').offsetHeight;
             document.getElementById('elemHeight').value = alto;
           return alto; 
       }                  
</script>
<pre> <code>
        <form action="/ficheroDestino.jsp">
              <input type="hidden" value="-1" id="elemHeight">
        </form>

Comment: así es, pero tienes que darle un `name` al input aparte del id para luego recogerlo en el otro jsp, y en el formulario poner `method="get/post"` según como lo quieras mandar, con get aparece en la url, con post no

Comment: Vale Muchas Gracias, que es mejor mandarlo por post o por get??

Comment: pues depende, si quieres que el usuario sepa que estas pasando ese dato como por ejemplo en una búsqueda (y se pueda editar facilmente desde la url) pues mejor por get, pero si es un dato que quieres mantener un poco mas oculto, o una contraseña o algo por post siempre.

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta para que veas como recoger el valor desde el jsp, puedes también revisar esta documentación bastante sencilla: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JSP/0090__JSP_Form_Processing.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad..estaba un poco perdido haha